# Creating .pptx file with OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I want to create a PowerPoint presentation based on a template in C#.
I am using the `OpenXML 2.0 SDK`.

My first step.

I took my .pptx template, changed it in C# code and copied it in my project.

1. I was able to create slides based on my templates.
2. Now i have some placeholders in my template i want to replace.

I found the following method, on the [msdn side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29#CreateDocswithOpenXMLSDK_CreatingaPresentationReportBasedonData)

```
void SwapPlaceholderText(SlidePart slidePart, string placeholder, string value) 
{ 
   //Find and get all the placeholder text locations. 
   List<Drawing.Text> textList = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<Drawing.Text>().Where(t => t.Text.Equals(placeholder)).ToList(); 
   //Swap the placeholder text with the text from DB 
   foreach (Drawing.Text text in textList) text.Text = value; 
}
```

But the size of the list is 0.
Does this method call even searching in the right method of my template?
The information of the placeholder i am searching for is in the following method of my template.

```
private void GenerateUserDefinedTagsPart5Content(UserDefinedTagsPart userDefinedTagsPart5)
{
 ...
 Tag tag71 = new Tag(){ Name = "FIELD.CHAPTER.CONTENT", Val = "#header#" };
 Tag tag72 = new Tag(){ Name = "FIELD.CHAPTER.VALUE", Val = "#header#" };
 ... }
```

What i am doing wrong? and how do i need to modify the placeholder-method?

Best regards!

**EDIT :** I found out some strange thing. I declared in my PowerPoint template a placeholder called "#header#" and in my program i was searching for "#header#" but after i ran the program once, the "#header#" in the PowerPoint file changed to "header" i don't know why but when i search now for "header" my list size is 1 and the header will be replaced.

But after running my program and want to start the PowerPoint presentation, it says the data is corrupted. Maybe you can see some mistakes:

This is my main method.

```
    Template template = new Template();
    template.CreatePackage("templatesource");

    PresentationDocument doc = PresentationDocument.Open("templatesource", true);
    PowerPoint powerPoint = new PowerPoint(doc, proj);
    powerPoint.AddNewSlides();
```

PowerPoint-class:

```
public void addSlides()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < proj.projects.Capacity; i++  )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Slide number: " + i);
        AddNewSlide(_document.PresentationPart);
    }
    _document.PresentationPart.Presentation.Save();
}

private void AddNewSlide(PresentationPart parent)
{
    if (_slideTemplate == null) return;

    var newSlidePart = parent.AddNewPart<SlidePart>("newSlide" + _slideId);

    newSlidePart.FeedData(_slideTemplate.GetStream(FileMode.Open));
    newSlidePart.AddPart(_slideTemplate.SlideLayoutPart, _slideTemplate.GetIdOfPart(_slideTemplate.SlideLayoutPart));

    SetPlaceholder(newSlidePart, "#header#", "My new header");

    newSlidePart.Slide.Save();

    SlideIdList listOfSlidesIDs = parent.Presentation.SlideIdList;
    uint maxSlideId = 1;

    foreach (SlideId slideId in listOfSlidesIDs.ChildElements)
    {
        if (slideId.Id > maxSlideId) maxSlideId = slideId.Id;
    }

    SlideId newSlideId = new SlideId { Id = ++maxSlideId, RelationshipId = parent.GetIdOfPart(newSlidePart) };
    listOfSlidesIDs.Append(newSlideId);

    _slideId++;  
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: do you still need help with this?